# Pass data to ui-grid inside ng-repeat in Angular

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-grid

I'm new to Angular and have been searching for a was to pass data from an iteration inside ng-repeat to a table that ui-grid is making.

I have a JSON-object which is structured similar to this:

```
{
 category1: {obj{atr1: val, atr2:val}, obj2{atr1: val, atr2:val}}, 
 category2: {obj{atr1: val, atr2:val}, obj2{atr1: val, atr2:val}}
}
```

I'm using ng-repeat to iterate over it similar to this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(category, objs) in jsonObj">
    <h3>{{category}}</h3>
    <div ui-grid="{ data: objs}" class="grid"></div>
</div>
```

This works for displaying the category name () but I can't figure out how to pass the objs to ui-grid. What is the right way to do this? Can I make a function and call it through data: and get the data that way? If I use just gridOptions and define the data in the .js all tables will get the same data, can I pass some variable from where the tables are being iterated so I can chose the correct data for each?

Comment: according to the [doc for uiGridOpotions](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions), the data field only supports array. Maybe u have to convert your data structure for each category into an array.

Comment: Aah, I'll have to look into this. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

```
<div ng-repeat="(category, objs) in jsonObj">
    <div ui-grid="{ data: jsonObj[category] }" class="grid"></div>
    </br>
</div>
```

This along with making the corresponding values lists (thanks MMhunter) works.